# PR2 head control segmentation fault

Tags: ros, boost, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I'm running PR2 in simulation with visual SLAM algorithm (in ROS electric), and a strange behaviour appears when I spawn the robot as his head falls :

[falling head http://anusite.free.fr/Documents/stageISIR/pr2_falling_head.png](http://anusite.free.fr/Documents/stageISIR/pr2_falling_head.png)

When I did the [simple_head tutorial]([www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Moving) the Head), duplicate the *point head* node to create a *raise head* node that uses the lookAt method to set the head in the right direction. Everything compiled and worked well till yesterday. I changed a value in the call to lookAt to ajust the direction and compiled again, but now the node is segfaulting at launch. Investigating a bit more showed that the segfault is in instantiating the **PointHeadClient** in constructor of RobotHead class.
I checked actionlib, controller messages, but they're built so they should be effective.

I think the problem may be correlated as I moved from boost 1.40 to 1.49 by copying files in boost_1_49_0/boost in /usr/include/boost as property tree are required by the visual SLAM I use.

Any advice is welcome :)

Thanks,
Erwan

EDIT : here is the code :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
#include <pr2_controllers_msgs/PointHeadAction.h>



// Our Action interface type, provided as a typedef for convenience
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<pr2_controllers_msgs::PointHeadAction> PointHeadClient;

class RobotHead
{
 private:
 PointHeadClient* point_head_client_;

public:
//! Action client initialization 
 RobotHead()
{
  //Initialize the client for the Action interface to the head controller
  point_head_client_ = new PointHeadClient("/head_traj_controller/point_head_action", true);
 std::cout << point_head_client_ << std::endl;
 //wait for head controller action server to come up 
 while(!point_head_client_->waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0)))
 {
  ROS_INFO("Waiting for the point_head_action server to come up");
  }
 }

~RobotHead()
{
   delete point_head_client_;
}

 //! Points the high-def camera frame at a point in a given frame  
 void lookAt(std::string frame_id, double x, double y, double z)
{
   //the goal message we will be sending
    pr2_controllers_msgs::PointHeadGoal goal;

    //the target point, expressed in the requested frame
     geometry_msgs::PointStamped point;
    point.header.frame_id = frame_id;
    point.point.x = x; point.point.y = y; point.point.z = z;
    goal.target = point;

    //we are pointing the high-def camera frame 
    //(pointing_axis defaults to X-axis)
    goal.pointing_frame = "high_def_frame";

    //take at least 0.5 seconds to get there
    goal.min_duration = ros::Duration(0.5);

    //and go no faster than 1 rad/s
    goal.max_velocity = 1.0;

    //send the goal
   point_head_client_->sendGoal(goal);

   //wait for it to get there (abort after 2 secs to prevent getting stuck)
    point_head_client_->waitForResult(ros::Duration(2));
 }

  //! Shake the head from left to right n times  
  void shakeHead(int n)
 {
   int count = 0;
   while (ros::ok() && ++count <= n )
    {
      //Looks at a point forward (x=5m), slightly left (y=1m), and 1.2m up
       lookAt("base_link", 5.0, 1.0, 1.2);

      //Looks at a point forward (x=5m), slightly right (y=-1m), and 1.2m up
      lookAt("base_link", 5.0, -1.0, 1.2);
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //init the ROS node
    ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_driver");

  RobotHead head;
  head.shakeHead(3);
  // The only difference in raisehead is that the previous line is replaced by :
  // head.lookAt("base_link", 2.0, 0.0, 0.8);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37784/pr2-head-control-segmentation-fault/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved using boost 1.41.0 but I don't think it's a good solution. If someone can update this tutorial with recent informations, it may help keeping ROS usable.

BtW, version 1.50 of boost looks absolutely not compatible with electric.

EDIT : as having some header-only libraries (and others to be compiled), Boost header-only files must be placed in a folder that is parsed when the compiler look for libraries and headers. The path :

```
/usr/include/
```

is an acceptable place for that (I don't know Linux well enough, but I think boost comes with the recent distributions - at least of Ubuntu - so there'll be a folder called boost in this directory). You just have to copy the boost_1_xx_y/boost subdirectory content into /usr/include/boost folder.
In my case, the upper code doesn't work with version 1.46 and more. As far as I know, it's a problem in the class instanciation. I need property_tree from boost to use the [OpenRatSLAM implementation](http://code.google.com/p/ratslam/), that are available from boost 1.41, so I downgraded to that version.
I think it's not a good solution as there are fixes in newer implementations of boost that are probably useful. Maybe tutorials would be revised to update the code with more up-to-date ROS classes and features. In my case, I'm only using a low importance program (raising head), but it's required to run RatSLAM (as it is visual SLAM).

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-05**:
So what did you do exactly? Even if it is a workaround, other people might benefit from it if you described it some more.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-05**:
The fact that Boost 1.50 is incompatible with electric shouldn't come as a surprise, see [reps/rep-0003](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#electric-emys-aug-2011) for more information. 1.50 is more than 10 minor releases newer than what Electric was developed for / with. Incompatibilities expected.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-05**:
Answer improved ;)

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-05**:
Boost is not a pure header-only library. There are a bunch of .so files, including threads, regexp and filesystem. Since many ros libraries and nodes link against at least boost thread, it's always a bad idea to use different headers in an own project without recompiling whole ROS.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-05**:
Ok so you mean that maybe the problem comes from the fact that I updated the header files and not the compiled librairies (I had some troubles understanding how to install boost the first time I had a problem of property_tree) ? - updated my answer to be more precise.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-05**:
@Lorenz: certain parts of boost *are* header only, but you are right, some are not. And as you point out (and I did earlier), mixing and matching versions is **not** a good idea, no matter how small the version difference (major / minor versions).

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-05**:
@Erwan R.: no, Lorenz is telling you that you cannot (in principle) mix different versions of Boost for use with ROS. The ROS packages are linked against a specific version of Boost, your nodes are then linked against ROS **and** against your newer version of Boost.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-05**:
@Erwan R.: it might be possible with header only libraries and taking some care with linking, but this is not trivial, and not a supported use case (I assume).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I think the problem may be correlated as I moved from boost 1.40 to 1.49 by copying files in boost_1_49_0/boost in /usr/include/boost as property tree are required by the visual SLAM I use.

So you copied a set of headers from a Boost v1.49 distribution to `/usr/include/boost` on a system that originally came with v1.40?

Depending on what exactly is using those new headers, and how isolated they are (ie: do they depend on other bits of Boost which you didn't copy), mixing & matching two Boost versions might not be such a good idea.

> Everything compiled and worked well till yesterday. I changed a value in the call to lookAt to ajust the direction and compiled again, but now the node is segfaulting at launch.

If you added the Boost v1.49 headers *before* recompiling your node, perhaps see if things start working again if you remove them and recompile? Segfaults are one possibility of having `version(header) != version(library)` for instance.

---

EDIT after the added answer and more info by @Erwan R.: See '[Using concurrently 2 versions of boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907882/using-concurrently-2-versions-of-boost)' on stackoverflow for some additional info on the problem. As I mentioned: it can be done, but probably requires quite some work.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-05**:
I went back to v1.40 and the segfault disappeared, but I strongly need a boost version that supports property_tree for another algorithm. I'm gonna investigate v1.50 or degrade to a version that is compatible with this node and has property_tree. (sry for 4-times comment)